# Dagger's module doesn't work after conversion from Java to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I create simple application for Android with Dagger 2. It has one shared object and one module. The module is:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Hren providesHren() {
        return new Hren();
    }
}
```

This module works. But when I convert it to Kotlin, I get compile time error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
...../DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        DoubleCheck.provider(MyModule_ProvidesHrenFactory.create(builder.myModule));
                             ^
  symbol:   variable MyModule_ProvidesHrenFactory
  location: class DaggerMyApplicationComponent
1 error
```

This module after conversion:

```
@Module
class MyModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesHren(): Hren {
        return Hren()
    }
}
```

What's wrong? Why I get this error? How to solve?

Comment: did you clean the project & rebuild it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have properly configured your project to support annotations with Kotlin.

In your `build.gradle(Module:app)` file, check that you have applied the following settings:

> - apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
> - kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:dagger_version"
> - kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:dagger_version"

Then, clean and rebuild your project:

> - ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build

Comment: Yep, I forgot that `annotationProcessor` works only with Java sources, for Kotlin I need `kapt`. Thank you.